# no route to host exception in android even when I use the right ip adress?

Tags: android, ip-address, httpconnection, connectionexception

So I get the `no route to host` exception in android and I don't know why...

Things i already did:

1. disabled firewall
2. granted internet permission in the manifest file
3. i use the same ip which I get in ipconfig
4. checked if I use the same network

This is my ip:
[image: ipconfig ipv4 adress]

using this ip can access my glassfish server: `http://192.168.1.2:8080/` but for some reason I can't connect my phone with this ip adress. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. 
The only thing I did was restarting the router.
When I restarted the router I got a new IPv4 adress and than I managed to connect myself with the new adress.